# How to call an external function?

Tags: fortran

I have the following function

```
REAL FUNCTION myfunction(x)

    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL, INTENT(IN) :: x
    myfunction = SIN(x)

END FUNCTION myfunction
```

in a file called `myfunction.f90`

I want to use this function in other f90 file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recommended way to do this in modern Fortran would be to create a module, let's call it e.g. "mymath". In that case, you can create one file `mymath.f90` containing something like this:

```
module mymath
contains
  function myfunction(x) result(r)
    real, intent(in) :: x
    real             :: r

    r = sin(x)
  end function
end module
```

Then another file `main.f90` like this:

```
program main
  use :: mymath

  print *,myfunction(3.1416/2)
end program
```

Then you just compile the source files together:

```
gfortran mymath.f90 main.f90
```

The resulting executable should work as expected.

**EDIT:**

If you really prefer to stay away from modules, then you can make `mymath.f` like this:

```
function myfunction(x) result(r)
  real, intent(in) :: x
  real             :: r

  r = sin(x)
end function
```

And make `main.f90` like this:

```
program main
  real, external :: myfunction

  print *,myfunction(3.1416/2)
end program
```

It compiles and works like the other solution. Note that if you choose to use `external` instead of `module`, the compiler will usually not check that the arguments you give to `myfunction` have the right number, types, and dimensions — which may complicate debugging in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I will wait if someone points out a straightforward way of calling the function without the module environment.

Comment: Although perhaps good practice, the `external` isn't required here.

Answer (score 1):

Just use external...

```
...
REAL, EXTERNAL :: myfunction
REAL           :: X, Y
...

Y = myfunction(x)
```

That said, it is wiser to let the compiler do what it does and catch the obvious issues that are easy to miss... so jabirali has a good approach.