# Fortran Newbie: How to Compile/Build multiple Fortran files in Geany

Tags: build, compilation, fortran, geany

I am new to Fortran and I am using the Geany IDE. I am looking at some old Fortran 90 with the goal of converting it to MATLAB. I am simplifying the problem and it may be a very simple newbie Fortran issue but I can't seem to find any explanation online.

Let's say I have a main program called "simple_program.f".

```
  program simple_program

  integer b  
  logical check
  
  call get_a(a)
  
  b = 2
  
  check = a < b
  
  write(*,*) check
  
  
  end
```

This main program calls a subroutine called "get_a" from a different program file called "a_in.f" which looks like this:

```
  subroutine get_a(a)

    integer a
  
    a = 1
  
  return
  end
```

When I try to compile simple_program.f in Geany, it gives an error when building saying "undefined reference to 'get_a'". If I try to compile a_in.f in Geany, it gives an error "undefined reference to 'WinMain'".

Three questions:

1. How do I link "simple_program.f" and "a_in.f" to tell Geany to compile them together? Looking online it seems I have to use a makefile but the Geany documentation is (in my opinion) atrocious in explaining how the "Build" menu works.
2. Can Fortran have files with only subroutines? If so, how does that work? The file a_in.f has no "main" program, it only contains a subroutine. But the scripts that I am looking at have clearly been compiled before since I have the executable.
3. Do you not have to explicitly define all variables at the top of the main program file if they are output from subroutines in other files? The main program (simple_program.f) does not define the variable "a" which I found surprising because I thought Fortran has to define all variables.

Any help navigating these issues is appreciated. Please assume I know very little. And any helpful beginner resources are appreciated as well.

Cheers

Comment: Not familiar with Geany, but with Fortran you need to explicitly tell it where to find the functions or variables that are defined in other files. Lots of questions related to this on SO, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333786/how-to-call-an-external-function

Comment: The problem is, you try to compile get_a.f as an executable (hence the error with WinMain, as there is no `program` unit). You have to compile as an object file that will be linked with the main program (simple_program.f). However, I don't know Geany, so I don't know how you do that in Geany. In a command line, it would be for instance `gfortran -c get_a.f` to produce the object file `get_a.o`, then `gfortran simple_program.f get_a.o` to build the executable.

Comment: Have a look at multi-file project section in  https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/compilers-and-ides/geany/creating-a-project .  It is for C but you can do the same thing with Fortran.

Comment: yes a file can contain only a subroutine.